# TensorFlow Ai not progressing, gym breakout-ram-v4

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I need help because when i run these line of code, my ai is not learning.
Could someone help me getting it to learn, i think the probleme is in the reward systeme but im not sure, thank you for your help.
can you help by or telling me how do make it better of by fixing it directly?

---

imports

---

```
import tensorflow as tf
import gym
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
```

---

```
#Load an environment
env = gym.make('Breakout-ram-v4')
```

---

making my agent

---

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, num_actions, state_size):

        initializer = tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()

        self.input_layer = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None, state_size])

        # Neural net starts here

        hidden_layer = tf.layers.dense(self.input_layer, 64, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=initializer)
        hidden_layer_2 = tf.layers.dense(hidden_layer, 32, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=initializer)

        dropout1 = tf.layers.dropout(hidden_layer_2, rate=0.1, training=True)

        hidden_layer_3 = tf.layers.dense(dropout1, 16, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer=initializer)

        dropout = tf.layers.dropout(hidden_layer_3, rate=0.2, training=True)

        # Output of neural net
        out = tf.layers.dense(dropout, num_actions, activation=None)

        self.outputs = tf.nn.softmax(out)
        self.choice = tf.argmax(self.outputs, axis=1)

        # Training Procedure
        self.rewards = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, ], dtype=tf.float32)
        self.actions = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, ], dtype=tf.int32)

        one_hot_actions = tf.one_hot(self.actions, num_actions)

        cross_entropy = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=out, labels=one_hot_actions)

        self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy * self.rewards)

        self.gradients = tf.gradients(self.loss, tf.trainable_variables())

        # Create a placeholder list for gradients
        self.gradients_to_apply = []
        for index, variable in enumerate(tf.trainable_variables()):
            gradient_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
            self.gradients_to_apply.append(gradient_placeholder)

        # Create the operation to update gradients with the gradients placeholder.
        optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
        self.update_gradients = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(self.gradients_to_apply, tf.trainable_variables()))
```

---

Reward systeme

---

```
discount_rate = 0.95
#its to make the reward
def discount_normalize_rewards(rewards):
    discount_rewards = np.zeros_like(rewards)
    total_rewards = 0
    for i in reversed(range(len(rewards))):
        total_rewards = total_rewards * discount_rate + rewards[i]
        discount_rewards[i] = total_rewards
        if discount_rewards[i] == 0:
            return discount_rewards
        else:
            discount_rewards /= np.std(discount_rewards)
            discount_rewards -= np.mean(discount_rewards)

        return discount_rewards
```

---

Trainning the ai

---

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

# Modify these to match shape of actions and states in your environment
num_actions = 4
state_size = 128
path = "./breakout-pg/"
training_episodes = 10000
max_steps_per_episode = 100000
episode_batch_size = 5

agent = Agent(num_actions, state_size)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=2)

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    total_episode_rewards = []

    # Create a buffer of 0'd gradients
    gradient_buffer = sess.run(tf.trainable_variables())
    for index, gradient in enumerate(gradient_buffer):
        gradient_buffer[index] = gradient * 0

    for episode in range(training_episodes):

        state = env.reset()

        episode_history = []
        episode_rewards = 0

        for step in range(max_steps_per_episode):
            env.render()

            # Get weights for each action
            action_probabilities = sess.run(agent.outputs, feed_dict={agent.input_layer: [state]})
            action_choice = np.random.choice(range(num_actions), p=action_probabilities[0])

            state_next, reward, done, _ = env.step(action_choice)
            episode_history.append([state, action_choice, reward, state_next])
            state = state_next

            episode_rewards += reward

            if done or step + 1 == max_steps_per_episode:
                total_episode_rewards.append(episode_rewards)
                episode_history = np.array(episode_history)
                episode_history[:,2] = discount_normalize_rewards(episode_history[:,2])

                ep_gradients = sess.run(agent.gradients, feed_dict={agent.input_layer: np.vstack(episode_history[:, 0]),
                                                                    agent.actions: episode_history[:, 1],
                                                                    agent.rewards: episode_history[:, 2]})
                # add the gradients to the grad buffer:
                for index, gradient in enumerate(ep_gradients):
                    gradient_buffer[index] += gradient

                break

        if episode % episode_batch_size == 0:

            feed_dict_gradients = dict(zip(agent.gradients_to_apply, gradient_buffer))

            sess.run(agent.update_gradients, feed_dict=feed_dict_gradients)

            for index, gradient in enumerate(gradient_buffer):
                gradient_buffer[index] = gradient * 0
#more frequent plz
        if episode % 10 == 0:
            saver.save(sess, path + "pg-checkpoint", episode)
            print("stage: " + str(episode) + "||| Average reward / 10 eps: " + str(np.mean(total_episode_rewards[-10:])))
print("done!")
```

Comment: i have a suspicion that it is in the last box, the action_probability or the action_choice